# JQuery Div follow during scrolling with top/bottom gap

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, fixed

I need a fixed div when scroll the page but between a top and a bottom value..
Now I have this code and it works but I can't find the solution to stop it when with the scroll I find the bottom of the page..
I want a bottom gap of 400px  (the height of my footer)..

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var el = jQuery('#news_right_cont');
    var elpos = el.offset().top;
    var gap = 174;
    jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
        var y = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
        if (y < elpos) {
            el.stop().animate({
                'top': 174
            }, 0);
        } else {
            el.stop().animate({
                'top': y - elpos + gap
            }, 0);
        }
    });
});
```

I hope you can find a solution..
Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry but I found that coding style of yours difficult to read

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to find if the scroll has reached the bottom of the page

```
 if (document.documentElement.clientHeight + y >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        //add your conditions                
    }
```

instead of your if else

```
if (y < elpos) {
            el.stop().animate({
                'top': 174
            }, 0);
        } else {
            el.stop().animate({
                'top': y - elpos + gap
            }, 0);
        }
```

add the following

```
if (document.documentElement.clientHeight + y + 400 < document.body.offsetHeight) {
                             el.stop().animate({ top: y - elpos + gap }, 0);
            }
```

You basically scroll only within the limits.
The number 400 in `document.documentElement.clientHeight + y + 40  you can be modified based on your footer location

Comment: Thanks arun..but how can I implement it in my function..I've tried but I can't find a solution..

Comment: added further comments..let me know if this helps

Comment: oops..need few more info  more 1. share ur div tag #news_right_cont'  2.add alert (document.documentElement.clientHeight);  alert(document.body.offsetHeight);            before ur if loop and share ur numbers.

Comment: it gives me 749 and 0.. the div doesn't follow the scroll... now I'm very confused.. :)